# Is there any option in BeautifulSoup to extract href from product title classes?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am making web scraper with BS4 and I am newbie in web scraping. Does anybody know how can I get back only hrefs from product title classes (prod_name)? The example for item can be iphone...

I want to get all links for each item searched from each webshop from the dictionary.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

item = input("Insert the name of the item you are searching for: ")

webshop_dict = [
    {'url': 'https://h2-shop.com/filterSearch?advs=true&cid=0&mid=0&vid=0&q=', 'prod_name': 'product-title'},
    {'url': 'https://www.instar-informatika.hr/search.asp?upit=', 'prod_name': 'name'},
    {'url': 'https://www.links.hr/hr/search?q=', 'prod_name': 'product-title'},
    {'url': 'https://www.mall.hr/trazenje?s=', 'prod_name': 'product-box-category__title',},
    {'url': 'https://mi.hr/filterSearch?q=', 'prod_name': 'product-title'},
    {'url': 'https://www.pcshop.hr/search.asp?upit=', 'prod_name': 'prdocutname'}
    ]

headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36"}
    
for shop in webshop_dict:
    page = requests.get(url=shop['url'] + item, headers = headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'lxml')  
    tags = ['a', 'p', 'span', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'div', 'ul', 'ol','ins', 'li','section','table','th', 'tb', 'label']

    #this for does not work 
    for link in soup.find_all(tags, class_ = shop['prod_name']).find_all("a").get('href'):
        print(link)
```

Comment: Hey @Arstegall Welcome to SO! if possible can you share your code or URL of that website you are working on!

Comment: Could you also mention the item for the convenience of people, all those webpages are not in english.

Comment: Yes, the sample for item can be iphone

Comment: Those are all different websites. You need to identify where the Product link is present inside every URL and then scrape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are all different websites. You need to identify where the Product link is present inside every URL and then scrape.

Eg:

```
{'url': f'https://www.pcshop.hr/search.asp?upit={item}', 'tag': 'div', 'class': 'product-image'}
```

> *The product links in this URL are present inside the tag `<div>` with class name as `product-image`.*

You have to see where the product links are present inside each URL and use that information in the `webshop_dict`.

Here I have scraped the product links from two of the mentioned URLs. You could easily extend this for all your URLs.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

item = 'iphone'

webshop_dict = [{'url': f'https://www.pcshop.hr/search.asp?upit={item}', 'tag': 'div', 'class': 'product-image'},
                {'url': f'https://www.mall.hr/mobilni-telefoni-apple-iphone?s={item}', 'tag': 'div', 'class': 'category-products__item'}]
headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36"}

for i in webshop_dict:
    r = requests.get(i['url'], headers=headers)
    print(f"\nProduct links in URL: {i['url']}\n")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    d = soup.find_all(i['tag'], class_=i['class'])
    for a in d:
        print(a.find('a')['href'])
```

```
Product links in URL: https://www.pcshop.hr/search.asp?upit=iphone

https://www.pcshop.hr/transmedia-flexible-hand-holder-for-iphones-usb-a-lightning/TRN%2DMH1/product/
https://www.pcshop.hr/transmedia-connecting-cable-for-iphone/TRN%2DCI12%2D1L/product/
https://www.pcshop.hr/transmedia-flexible-red-cable-usb-type-a-plug-to-to-8-pin-plug-1m/TRN%2DC525%2D1R/product/
https://www.pcshop.hr/transmedia-flexible-blue-cable-usb-type-a-plug-to-usb-type-c-plug-1m/TRN%2DC525%2D1B/product/
https://www.pcshop.hr/gembird-usb-type-c-female-to-8-pin-male-adapter-plug/GEM%2DA%2DUSB%2DCF8PM%2D01/product/
https://www.pcshop.hr/transmedia-audio-kabel-for-iphone-white/TRN%2DAI3%2DWL/product/
https://www.pcshop.hr/transmedia-usb-car-charger/TRN%2DWI%2D11L/product/
https://www.pcshop.hr/roline-touchclean-sredstvo-za-ciscenje-smartphonetablet-uredaja/19%2E03%2E3145/product/
https://www.pcshop.hr/transmedia-connecting-cable-for-iphone-ipad-ipod-smartphone-and-tablets/TRN%2DCI22%2DL/product/
https://www.pcshop.hr/gembird-universal-charger-21-a-black-color/GEM%2DEG%2DUC2A%2D02/product/
https://www.pcshop.hr/kabel-sbox-usb-iph7-mm-15m-zlatno-roza-2kom/wire%2Diph7%2Dpinkgold/product/
https://www.pcshop.hr/transmedia-charging-lightning-cable-for-iphone-1m-reversible/TRN%2DM17%2DL/product/
https://www.pcshop.hr/slusalice-canyon-hsc-1-basic-pc-headset-with-microphone-combined-35mm-plug-leather-pads-flat-cable-length-20m-16060160mm-013kg-black-red/CNS%2DCHSC1BR/product/
https://www.pcshop.hr/canyon-hsc-1-basic-pc-headset-with-microphone-combined-35mm-plug-leather-pads-flat-cable-length-20m-16060160mm-013kg-black/CNS%2DCHSC1B/product/
https://www.pcshop.hr/roline-value-adapter-8-pin-micro-b-mf/11%2E99%2E8324/product/
https://www.pcshop.hr/verbatim-punjac-power-pack-ultra-tanki-prijenosni-crveni-4200mah/V098453/product/
https://www.pcshop.hr/panasonic-slusalice-rp-tcm115e-p-roze/02391037/product/
https://www.pcshop.hr/kabel-usb-za-android-i-iphone-bijeli-x-5/wire%2D2in1mob%2Dwx5/product/
https://www.pcshop.hr/transmedia-usb-car-charger/TRN%2DWI%2D12L/product/
https://www.pcshop.hr/panasonic-slusalice-rp-tcm115e-a-plave/02391040/product/
https://www.pcshop.hr/slusalice-hp-inear-plave-2ap91aa/0381905/product/
https://www.pcshop.hr/slusalice-hp-za-prijenosno-racunalo-x7b04aa/0377879/product/
https://www.pcshop.hr/canyon-headphones-detachable-cable-with-microphone-foldable-black/CNE%2DCHP2/product/
https://www.pcshop.hr/charge-sync-mfi-braided-cable-with-metalic-shell-usb-to-lightning-certified-by-apple-1m-028mm-dark-gray/CNS%2DMFIC3DG/product/
https://www.pcshop.hr/roline-value-usb-car-charger-2-port-21a/19%2E99%2E1059/product/
https://www.pcshop.hr/canyon-type-c-cable-to-mfi-lightning-for-apple-pvc-moulingfunctionwith-full-feature-data-transmission-and-pd-charging-output5v24a-od35mm-cable-length-12m-0026kgcolorblack/CNS%2DMFIC4B/product/
https://www.pcshop.hr/canyon-type-c-cable-to-mfi-lightning-for-apple-pvc-moulingfunction-with-full-feature-data-transmission-and-pd-charging-output5v24a-od35mm-cable-length-12m-0026kgcolorwhite/CNS%2DMFIC4W/product/
https://www.pcshop.hr/pametna-narukvica-neon-m4-roza/125943/product/
https://www.pcshop.hr/pametna-narukvica-neon-m4-plava/125942/product/
https://www.pcshop.hr/pametna-narukvica-neon-m4-crna/125940/product/

Product links in URL: https://www.mall.hr/mobilni-telefoni-apple-iphone?s=iphone

/mobilni-telefoni-apple-iphone/apple-telefon-iphone-11-64gb-crveni
/mobilni-telefoni-apple-iphone/apple-iphone-11-mobilni-telefon-64gb-ljubicasti
/mobilni-telefoni-apple-iphone/apple-iphone-11-mobilni-telefon-128gb-crni
/mobilni-telefoni-apple-iphone/apple-iphone-11-mobilni-telefon-128gb-bijeli
/mobilni-telefoni-apple-iphone/apple-iphone-2020-mobilni-telefon-64-gb-bijela
/mobilni-telefoni-apple-iphone/apple-iphone-12-pro-pametni-telefon-256gb-graphite
/mobilni-telefoni-apple-iphone/apple-iphone-12-pro-pametni-telefon-128gb-pacific-blue
/mobilni-telefoni-apple-iphone/apple-iphone-11-mobilni-telefon-128gb-ljubicasti
/mobilni-telefoni-apple-iphone/apple-iphone-12-pro-pametni-telefon-512gb-silver
/mobilni-telefoni-apple-iphone/apple-iphone-12-mini-mobilni-telefon-128gb-blue
/mobilni-telefoni-apple-iphone/apple-iphone-12-pametni-telefon-64gb-white
/mobilni-telefoni-apple-iphone/apple-iphone-12-pametni-telefon-64-gb-purple
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first find main `h2` tag with class and then `a` tag where you can extract `href` from it!

```
html="""<h2 class="product-title"><a href="/APC-NBPD0123">APC NetBotz CCTV Adapter Pod 120</a></h2>
"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
soup.find("h2",class_="product-title").find("a")['href']
```

Output:

```
'/APC-NBPD0123'
```

OR:

```
soup.find("h2",class_="product-title").find("a").get('href')
```